# Regular Expression between Ranges

Tags: c#, regex

Having a method that takes an amount as an argument and return after comparing with Range{minRange, maxRange} like {5,100} or {100,500} etc

Trying to construct a regular expression that will validate that Input amount is in between Range of {5,100} or {100,500} or {200,2000}.

Note: MinRange & MaxRanges values are changes after some constant interval of time. 
Please advise

Comment: Which language are you using? I'm not convinced that regular expressions are the right tool for the job.

Comment: using C# but I am forced to do regular expression because I cannot refactor whole logic...

Comment: Could you post some code that demonstrates any relevant parts that can't be changed?

Comment: Are the ranges *arbitrary* ones, e.g. is it possible, say `[2388..79453]`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko No arbitrary ranges... MinRange is actual minimum amount and maxRange is maximum amount for a particular Service. 
Actual amount must be in between minimum amount and maximum amount.

Comment: *"I am forced to do regular expression because I cannot refactor whole logic"*: It's a sign that you have a bad design. Even if changing it (to be able to test a numeric range with simple functions) seems to require more work and time, do it. This is the sane attitude. It's better than trying to write a tortured pattern (even if it is doable for this case), and will give you more freedom for eventual other tests for which using a regex is awkward.

Comment: Could you give a code? It's not clear what is Range{minRange,maxRange} notation. Is it a string? An object?

Comment: @JohnyL actually WPF User-control is taking regex as Input and verifying UserInput amount based on that...  minRange & maxRange is amount Range like minimum amount and maximum amount. 

I constructed below Regex but it is also matching number greater then 1000 as well. if you know, advise to fix the issue
    ^(?:[5-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,4}*|1000)$

Answer (score 0):

Following regular expression can be used to validate/verify that the given input is in-between Ranges

```
^(?:[5-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}?|1000)$
```